# Search API: Custom processor not hitting addFieldValues

Tags: search

I'm creating a custom module for adding a processor that adds relative entities. Here's my code for **getPropertyDefinition**.

```
public function getPropertyDefinitions(DatasourceInterface $datasource = NULL) {
$properties = [];
if ($datasource) {
  $entity_type = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('group_type')->load(key($datasource->getBundles()));
  $entity_type_ids = [];
  $plugin_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.group_content_enabler')->getInstalled();
  foreach($plugin_manager->getInstanceIds() as $instance_id) {
    array_push($entity_type_ids, $plugin_manager->get($instance_id)->getPluginDefinition()['entity_type_id']);
  }
  foreach($entity_type_ids as $entity_type_id) {
    $definition = [
      'label' => $this->t(ucwords($entity_type_id)),
      'description' => $this->t('Entity reference of ' . $entity_type_id),
      'type' => 'entity:' . $entity_type_id,
      'processor_id' => $this->getPluginId(),
    ];
    $properties[$entity_type_id] = new EntityProcessorProperty($definition);
    $properties[$entity_type_id]->setEntityTypeId($entity_type_id);
  }
}
return $properties;
}
```

And, after adding relative fields to index, I think it should hit **addFieldValues** method but it doesn't. For test purpose, I only put die in the method.

```
public function addFieldValues(ItemInterface $item) {die;}
```

But, when I copied code from addURI's **getPropertyDefinition** into my **getPropertyDefinition**, it hits **addFieldValues** when indexing. Is there anything wrong in my **getPropertyDefinition**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for a module and needs to be handled in the issue queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
I created an issue on the search API issue queue Custom Entity Reference processor does not trigger addFieldValues()* and the maintainer has pointed to an existing issue that it was duplicating. So there is an existing issue that is being worked on here - [#2910638: Entity reference via processor sample code not working](https://www.drupal.org/node/2910638) Jump on there and help test :)

- I couldn't post the first link because of a lack of reputation and I figured the link to the issue where work is being carried out is more useful :D

I'm encountering the same behaviour and have an idea why this occurs but not an answer on how to fix it (I can't post a comment so needed to add this as an answer).

`\Drupal\search_api\Item\Item::getFields` is responsible for calling the instances' implementation of `addFieldValues`. Within that function there is this code block:

```php
   foreach ($this->index->getFieldsByDatasource($datasource_id) as $field_id => $field) {
      // Don't overwrite fields that were previously set.
      if (empty($this->fields[$field_id])) {
        $this->fields[$field_id] = clone $field;

        $field_data_type = $this->fields[$field_id]->getType();
        // If the field data type is in the fallback mapping list, then use
        // the fallback type as field type.
        if (isset($data_type_fallback_mapping[$field_data_type])) {
          $this->fields[$field_id]->setType($data_type_fallback_mapping[$field_data_type]);
        }

        $property = $field->getDataDefinition();
        if ($property instanceof ProcessorPropertyInterface) {
          $processors_with_fields[$property->getProcessorId()] = TRUE;
        }
        elseif ($datasource_id) {
          $fields_by_property_path[$field->getPropertyPath()][] = $this->fields[$field_id];
        }
      }
    }
    try {
      if ($fields_by_property_path) {
        \Drupal::getContainer()
          ->get('search_api.fields_helper')
          ->extractFields($this->getOriginalObject(), $fields_by_property_path, $this->getLanguage());
      }
      if ($processors_with_fields) {
        $processors = $this->index->getProcessorsByStage(ProcessorInterface::STAGE_ADD_PROPERTIES);
        foreach ($processors as $processor_id => $processor) {
          if (isset($processors_with_fields[$processor_id])) {
            $processor->addFieldValues($this);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

If the value of `$property` is not an instanceof `ProcessorPropertyInterface` then `addFieldValues()` is never called.

What I'm not sure of is what is the best path to take to begin solving this.

- Should I add a new custom processor that only acts on this custom field and use `addFieldValues()` there? (I've yet to test this) OR
- Is it an issue that `addFieldValues()` is never called and the Search API module needs to be updated so that it is?

I've tried implementing the other functions from the parent class (`\Drupal\search_api\Processor\ProcessorPluginBase`) ie `alterIndexedItems` but none of those are triggered.

I came across the same approach that you're using here on d.o - [Adding an entity reference via a processor](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/developer-documentation/adding-an-entity-reference-via-a-processor) so it may be the docs need to be updated.

Comment: Great. The new patch hits the method now. Thank you very much!